Workaround for chaining ::part() selector with other selectors in chromium based browsers?
I was trying to use chain :disabled, :not([disabled]) and/or :not([aria-label='']) with ::part() but I have found that it does not work in chromium based browsers as mentioned in the answer here. It appears that the bug still hasn't been solved.
Our client uses only Chrome and Edge for their webapps.
Is there any workaround for this bug?
What I am trying to do is find element (in shadow root) that - for example - has part and disabled attribute (or is explicitly not disabled).
I want to match elements like one below. (This <td> element might have disabled attribute)
<td role="gridcell" part="date" tabindex="-1" aria-label="1 Czerwiec 2024, sobota">1</td>

In example below. The button is disabled and thus should have orange color text because of the selector .app-1::part(button-1):disabled. The .app-1::part(label-1):hover selector for label somehow works.


let template = document.querySelector('.temp-1').innerHTML;
let shadowElement = document.querySelector('.app-1');
let shadow = shadowElement.attachShadow({
  mode: 'open'
});

shadow.innerHTML = template;
<template class="temp-1">
  <div part="label-1">
    Label encapsulated in Shadow DOM
  </div>
  <button part="button-1" disabled>
    Click me!
  </button>
</template>
<style>
  .app-1 {
    color: green;
    background-color: lightblue;
  }

  .app-1::part(label-1):hover {
    color: orange;
  }

  .app-1::part(button-1) {
    color: lime;
  }

  .app-1::part(button-1):disabled {
    color: orange;
  }

</style>
<div class="app-1"></div>




I guess the only way out is to track disabled yourself on every click. But to check every change (when disabled is changed without a click) you would also need a MutationObserver. This Chromium bug on :disabled affects more, when used in a CSS group it breaks all CSS. I have added this to the Chromium bug report hopefully this will trigger some activity

@Danny'365CSI'Engelman looks like your comment on this issue indeed sparked some activity. The bug was marked as fixed today.

okay, I haven't gotten any feedback, so I presume they close issues with notification. But it is (supposed to be) fixed Yeah!

CSSPartAllowsMoreSelectorsAfter to be released in Chromium 130 https://chromiumdash.appspot.com/schedule mid october
